# tomee plus 1.7.2 - /bin/java: No such file or directory error

Tags: apache-tomee

I'm getting the following error when starting TOMEE plus 1.7.2:

```
/home/atom/tomee-apps/boss/bin/catalina.sh: line 392: /opt/oracle/jdk/jdk1.8.0_60/jre
/bin/java: No such file or directory
```

If I do below from console, it works, which means that the java file does exist:

```
[atom@ustxplmadevapp1 bin]$ /opt/oracle/jdk/jdk1.8.0_60/jre/bin/java -version
java version "1.8.0_60"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_60-b27)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.60-b23, mixed mode)
```

The startup.sh console output is like below:

```
[atom@ustxplmadevapp1 bin]$ ./startup.sh
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /home/atom/tomee-apps/boss
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /home/atom/tomee-apps/boss
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /home/atom/tomee-apps/boss/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /opt/oracle/jdk/jdk1.8.0_60/jre
Using CLASSPATH:       /home/atom/tomee-apps/boss/bin/bootstrap.jar:/home/atom/tomee-apps/boss/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Using CATALINA_PID:    /var/apps/apache-tomee-plus-1.7.2/boss/tomcat.pid
Existing PID file found during start.
Removing/clearing stale PID file.
Tomcat started.
```

The setenv.sh is as of below:

```
JRE_HOME="/opt/oracle/jdk/jdk1.8.0_60/jre"
CATALINA_PID="/var/apps/apache-tomee-plus-1.7.2/boss/tomcat.pid"
```

Any idea why I'm getting such error?  I've notice that the error always has a line break between /opt/oracle/jdk/jdk1.8.0_60/jre and /bin/java.  Not sure if that is the cause of what.

Comment: Have you tried recently released TomEE version 1.7.3 already? Just a thought.